# Combined sql statement into linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert a complex sql statement into a linq lambda expression.

Here is an example of my sql - statement:

```
select * from Kunden 
where a=1 
and b=1 
and c=1 
and ( 
( 
(d=1 or d in (2, 3, 4, 5)) <---
and e in (1, 2, 3) 
) 
or 
( 
(f=1 or f in (2, 3, 4, 5)) <---
and g in (1, 2, 3) 
) 
) 
) 
and h=1 
and i=1
```

at least I am freaking out about the brackets in the combined or statement. 
Need some help to convert this statement into linq expression. I cant fire the native sql on the server, because we have a complex linq expression (about 3000 lines of code :-X) we can´t convert it to sql.

In conclusion: I NEED THE LINQ EXPRESSION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it by using Contains in Linq, as the example below shows:

```
List<int> valuesOne = new List<int> { 2,3,4,5 };
List<int> ValuesTwo = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };

var myLinq = (from k in Kunden
             where k.a == 1 && k.b == 1 && k.c == 1 &&
             ((k.d == 1 || ValuesOne.Contains (k.d)) &&
                         ValuesTwo.Contains (k.e))) ||
             // now do the same for f
```

I'm not quite sure about the placement of brackets because I'm not at a development machine, but using Contains is probably the best way to do it

Comment: Thank you it´s working fine! could be easier? :-D Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
where ... new[] {2, 3, 4, 5}.Contains(d)
```